# ExpressJS setting up SEO friendly route

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization

I am new to `NodeJS` and I am experiencing a problem while setting up my routes. I am using `i18next`, `i18next-express-middleware` and `i18next-node-fs-backend` in order to create a multilingual test website.

I would like my `URL` to look like the following depending on the selected language:

- `/fr/index`, for french,
- `/en/index`, for english,
- `/jp/index`, for japanese.

I am currently facing at least one problem. The default route does not send me to the correct `URL`. I am always directed to `/`.

Here is my `server.js` file:

```
'use strict';
var debug = require('debug');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var i18next = require('i18next');
var i18nextMiddleware = require('i18next-express-middleware');
var backend = require('i18next-node-fs-backend');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

i18next
    .use(backend)
    .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        backend: {
            loadPath: __dirname + '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
            addPath: __dirname + '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json'
        },
        ns: ["ns.common"],
        defaultNS: "ns.common",
        fallbackNS: "ns.common",
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        preload: ['en', 'fr', 'jp'],
        saveMissing: true,
        removeLngFromUrl: false,
        detection: {
            order: ['path', 'session', 'querystring', 'cookie', 'header']
        },
    });
app.use(i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next));

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Here is my `index.js` file:

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/:lng', function (req, res) {
    res.header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    res.render('index', {});
});

module.exports = router;
```

The project is articulated as follows:

```
locales
  |_en
    ns.common.json
  |_fr
    ns.common.json
  |_jp
    ns.common.json
public
  |_fonts
  |_images
  |_javascripts
  |_stylesheets
routes
  index.js
  user.js
views
server.js
```

Everything is working fine if I enter manually the `URL`.

Can someone help me detect what is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

### Edit

As pointed out by Kishan, I use the following code, in order to redirect users to the correct locale. Thus, I am using a cookie to store the locale of a user. I ddo not know if it is a safe nor the most optimized way of doing things, but it works.

Here is the index file:

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect(req.cookies.locale + '/index');
});

router.get('/:lng/index', function (req, res) {
    res.header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    res.render('index', {});
});

/* Change locale */
router.post('/locale', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('locale', req.body.locale, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
    res.json({ status: 'success',  redirect: '/' + req.body.locale + '/index'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a route for `/` (root) in the index.js.

In the above code, the route gets into index.js but not find the path for `/`(root).

So add the route like...

`router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // YOUR LOGIC
});`

in your index.js.

Comment: This is what I was originally doing by redirecting everyone to /:lng depending on their locale. But I am not sure if it was the most optimized way to stick with.